# What does it mean that x $\in$ a and x $\notin$ $\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given a problem where I have to prove that A + $\emptyset$ = A, where operation
A + B = (A - B) $\cup$ (B - A).

I have A + $\emptyset$ = (A - $\emptyset$) $\cup$ ($\emptyset$ - A). This means that **x $\in$ A and x $\notin$ $\emptyset$** or **x $\in$ $\emptyset$ and x $\notin$ A**.

But I don't understand what it means for x to be an element and not to be an element of empty set. Could you please explain it ?

Comment: for any $x$, $x\not\in\emptyset$, and not $x\in\emptyset$

Comment: So I continue my proof: Therefore, the latter statement is false, hence x $\in$ A and $\notin$ $\emptyset$. This means that x $\in$ A.    Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you've got it!

Comment: A more common notation is $A \triangle B$, the collection of elements that are in either $A$ or $B$ but **not** in both.

Comment: Did you mean $\emptyset$ instead of $a$ in the title?

Comment: Note that $\emptyset$ contains nothing so it is always true that $x \notin \emptyset$.

Comment: J.W Tanner yes, I meant $\emptyset$.

Comment: It's one or the other.  It is not both.  Either [$x \in A$ and $x\not\in \emptyset$] *OR* [$x\in \emptyset$ and $x \not \in A$]$.  (Notice, one of those is possible but the other is not.)

Comment: Another way to think of it:  $A-\emptyset = \{x\in A|x\not \in \emptyset\}=\{x\in A\} = A$.  And $\emptyset-A =\{x\in \emptyset|x\not \in A\}=\{\} =\emptyset$.  So $(A-\emptyset)\cup (\emptyset-A)= A\cup \emptyset=\{x\in A\}\cup \{\} = \{x\in A\} = A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in A$ and $x\notin\emptyset$ or $x\in\emptyset$ and $x\notin A$

means $x\in A $ and $x\notin\emptyset$ (since we can't have $x\in\emptyset$).

But, for all $x$, $x\notin\emptyset$, so this means $x\in A$.